# Will compiler automatically optimize repeating code?

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-optimization

If I have some code with simple arithmetics that is repeating several times. Will the compiler automatically optimize it?

Here the example:

```
someArray[index + 1] = 5;
otherArray[index + 1] = 7;
```

Does it make sense to introduce variable `nextIndex = index + 1` from the perfomance point of view, (not from the point of view of good readable and maintanable code) or the compiler will do such optimization automatically?

Comment: Well, if index is a fundamental integral type, most likely it will with optimizations enabled.

Comment: Why don't you build with optimization enabled, and check the generated code?

Comment: Compile it and check the assembly.  Conceivably it could but I'm doubtful.

Comment: @specializt these are not the same object being indexed. Even if they were, a non-inlined overloaded `operator []` could throw the optimizer off.

Comment: oh ... misread it.

Comment: It somewhat depends on the rest of the code around it.  For example it might even decide to optimise by binning the entire array altogether.

Comment: It depends on the actual `operator[]` used - in some cases, using the `nextIndex` variable could be worse than not using it. This is such a common operation that most modern CPU have specific instruction for doing such things, see by yourself: https://godbolt.org/g/cw8jCb

Comment: Guys, I don't know assembly language to check the generated code.

Comment: Not sure if we can help you then...Someone has to be able to determine if it worked or not, it is certainly not guaranteed, optimizers do what they are programmed to do and no reason to assume any two behave the same so "it depends" is the best answer here, and to determine if ti did you either need to correctly and accurately time it (which can be harder than reading assembly language, which isnt that hard at all if you are a programmer) or inspect the code.  inspecting the code doesnt mean you automatically know it is faster, less instructions doesnt necessarily mean faster.

Comment: @Brans - The short version is that the compiler translated `someArray[index + 1] = 5;` into a single machine instruction. This code is so common that the x86 has special hardware for array indexing, including adding a small offset. It is hard for you to improve that any more.

Answer (score 2):

You should not worry about trivial optimization like this because almost all compilers do it last 10-15 years or longer.

But if you have a really critical place in your code and want to get maximal speed of running, than you can check generated assembler code for this lines to be sure that compiler did this trivial optimization.

In some cases one more arithmetic addition could be more faster version of code than saving in register or memory, and compilers knows about this. You can make your code slower if you try optimize trivial cases manually.

And you can use online services like https://gcc.godbolt.org for check generated code (support gcc, clang, icc in several version).

Answer (score 1):

The old adage "suck it and see" seems to be appropriate here. We often forget that by far the most common processors are 4/8/16 bit micros with weird and wonderful application specific architectures and suitably odd vendor specific compilers to go with them. They frequently have compiler extensions to "aid" (or confuse) the compiler into producing "better" code.

One DSP from early 2000s carried out 8 instructions per clock-cycle in parallel in a pipeline (complex - "load+increment+multiply+add+round"). The precondition for this to work was that everything had to be preloaded into the registers beforehand. This meant that registers were obviously at a premium (as always). With this architecture it was frequently better to bin results to free registers and use free slots that couldn't be paralleled (some instructions precluded the use of others in the same cycle) to recalculate it later. Did the compiler get this "right"?. Yes, it often kept the result to reuse later with the result that it stalled the pipeline due to lack of registers which resulted in slower execution speed.

So, you compiled it, examined it, profiled it etc. to make sure that the when when the compiler got it "right" we could go in and fix it. Without additional semantic information which is not supported by the language it is really hard to know what "right" is.

Conclusion: Suck it and see

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's a common optimization. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination